# Creating a backup copy of Active Sheet using Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, backup, worksheet

I need to create a backup copy of active Sheet - into a new workbook.
So that the new workbook would be created with only Active Sheet in it (no macro, no vba)

I need it to be happening on "After Opening" my Worksheet event

Doing the following:

```
     Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "E:\Projects\FolderName\FileName.xlsm"
                         
     End Sub
```

It copies the entire Workbook, with all the vba code and macro in it, not what I need.

Is there a way to only copy the Active Sheet?

Ideally, I would wanted to have cell reference (I store the file path in a different sheet, in a separated cell named "BackupPath").

Comment: Is "BackupPath" a named range? If you do not need macro, you should save the workbook as xlsx. Does your named range contain the extension, also?

Comment: @FaneDuru Is "BackupPath" a named range? - it's a named cell, where I store path for my exported file. Ideally I would want a reference to that cell, instead of typing path in vba, as I showed in my post.  About the 2nd part - I tried saving as xlsx - and received error message when opened saved file - "Excel cannot open file, because extension or format is not valid" and was unable to open it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim wb As Workbook, shC As Worksheet
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, strBackup As String, arr As Variant
  
  Set shC = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'this should be clear...
  strBackup = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("BackupPath")).Value 'extract the string from the named range
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add             'open a new workbook
   shC.Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1) 'copy the active sheet before the existing one
   If wb.Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
        'delete all sheets, except the first
        For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 2 Step -1
          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Worksheets(i).Delete
          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Next i
   End If
   arr = Split(strBackup, ".") 'split the path on the dot "."
                               'the last array element will be extension
   arr(UBound(arr)) = "xlsx"   'change exiting extension with "xlsx"
   strBackup = Join(arr, ".")  'join the processed array and obtain the correct path
   wb.SaveAs strBackup, xlWorkbookDefault 'save the workbook
   wb.Close False                         'close it without saving
   
   MsgBox "A backup has been done, like " & strBackup
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG, it worked perfectly   (looks very complex too)......Thank you

Comment: @Hell-1931: Glad I could help! The code is not so complex... I will comment its lines and you will understand it without problems, I think/hope... :)

Comment: @Thank you !!!  Would be so much easier, I'll go thru step by step tomorrow (my morning)...  works perfect

Comment: @Hell-1931: Placed relevant comments on any line...

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Var_Path = "D:...\Wb2.xls"
File1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks.Open Var_Path, 0, ReadOnly:=False

File2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(File1).Sheets("Feuil1").Copy Before:=Workbooks(File2).Sheets("Feuil3")
End Sub
```

(Find here : [Some Forum subject](https://forums.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-7228040-vba-excel-copie-feuille-dans-autre-classeur))

To open from another cell you can replace `Var_Path = "D:...\Wb2.xls"` by `Var_Path = range("A1").text` (Considering Range A1 is your cell "BackupPath")

Comment: Sorry, but what is <..... File2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(File1).Sheets("Feuil1").Copy Before:=Workbooks(File2).Sheets("Feuil3")...>
I only have one sheet (Active sheet which I need to create a backup copy)

Comment: It's exactly the same process when you try to copy a sheet manually, Excel ask where you want to paste it. In my example, this is before the sheet 3 in the backup file :)

So here the code copy the sheet 1 from your active workbook to paste it before the sheet 3 of another workbook.

Comment: Ok, so, if I want to paste my "Sheet1" from active workbook into the new workbook without any other sheets - in this case, I'd write:

File2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(File1).Sheets("Feuil1").Copy    or just - Workbooks(File1).Sheets("Feuil1")?

Comment: File2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name Workbooks(File1).Sheets("Sheet1")  sorry

Comment: No, I don't think it will works in this case... But you can still have an unused sheet just for that otherwise, for the first backup you can select all your cells in the first workbook then select the range A1 in your backup file and paste. In fact you replace the empty file with your sheet. To know if it's the first backup, you just need to add a condition to count the number of sheets in your backup file.

Comment: I tried as following:

<......
.Var_Path = "E:\Projects\Client Satisfaction Survey\ClientSatisfactionSurvey2020.xlsx"
File1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks.Open Var_Path, 0, ReadOnly:=False

File2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(File1).Sheets("ClientSatisfactionForm").Copy Before:=Workbooks(File2).Sheets("Feuil3")
......>

where "ClientSatisfactionForm" is the name of my sheet I need to backup

getting error "Excel cannot open because file format is not valid"